# Keep uppercase after / in a string

Tags: python, capitalization

I'm trying to title the following string:

`"Men's L/S long sleeve"`

I'm using `string.capwords` right now but it's not working as expected.

For example:

```
x = "Men's L/s Long Sleeve"
y = string.capwords(x)
print(y)
```

outputs:

`Men's L/s Long Sleeve`

but I want:

`Men's L/S Long Sleeve` (uppercased S after the /)

Is there an easy way to go about doing this?

Comment: You could use `str.replace` to get a space after the slash, then capitalise, then remove the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by /, then run capwords individually on all the components, then rejoin the components

```
text = "Men's L/s Long Sleeve"
"/".join(map(string.capwords, text.split("/")))
Out[10]: "Men's L/S Long Sleeve"
```

Comment: Going to mark as solved since this solved the specific question. I have a followup question though if you don't mind. Let's say I wanted to keep capitalization after all punctuation. Would I need to iterate over string.punctuation and then execute the above code?

Comment: @RonakVora That would work I guess but it's not very efficient or robust. Maybe just write your own implementation of capwords instead of running capwords and trying to fix it after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on '/', use string.capwords on each substring, and rejoin on '/':

```
import string

'/'.join(string.capwords(s) for s in "Men's L/S long sleeve".split('/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `/` might not be a reliable indicator that a capital letter is needed. In case the more reliable indicator is actually that the letter was capitalised originally, you could try iterating through each string and only extracting the letters got promoted to upper:

```
import string
x = "Men's L/S long sleeve"
y = string.capwords(x)
z = ''
for i,l in enumerate(x):
    if(l.isupper()):
        z += l
    else:
        z += y[i]
```

So on strings like:

```
"brand XXX"
"shirt S/M/L"
"Upper/lower"
```

You'll get:

```
"Brand XXX"
"Shirt S/M/L"
"Upper/lower"
```

Which I think it probably more desirable than using the `/` as an indicator.