# Capitalizing first letter of each token of a string split on punctuation and whitespace

Tags: python, capitalization

I'm trying to title the following string:

`"Men's L/s button-up"`

I'm using `string.capwords` right now but it's not working as expected.

For example:

```
x = "Men's L/s button-up"
y = string.capwords(x)
print(y)
```

outputs:

`Men's L/s Button-up`

but I want:

`Men's L/S Button-Up` (uppercased S after the / and uppercased U after the -)

More generally, how do I ensure that all letters following a space or punctuation are capitalized?

This is a follow-up from:

[Keep uppercase after / in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411174/keep-uppercase-after-in-a-string)

Comment: _how do I ensure that all letters following a space or punctuation are capitalized_ In that case, wouldn't you want `Men'S` ?

Comment: Likely, he doesn't consider an apostrophe to be a _relevant_ punctuation symbol. That being said, I agree, he should've formed his conditions more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `string.capwords` won't work for this, because internally, it uses `str.split()` to generate tokens ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#string.capwords)). `str.split()` can only split on runs of whitespace (default behavior) or using a user-specified character/string ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)). If a string is specified, it is considered as a whole, and not as separated characters.

To achieve what you want, I would use regular expressions, for example:

```
import re

x = "Men's L/s button-up"
y = re.sub(r'[\w]+', lambda m: m.group(0).capitalize(), x)
print(y)
# "Men'S L/S Button-Up"
```

`re.sub` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)) can be used to replace substrings inside the given string. The second argument there is a function that takes a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) argument and returns the replacement string (in this case, we capitalize the full match).

If you stumble across this question, also make sure to look at @Christian answer just below this, as it provides a nice alternative way to split the string :)

Comment: Nice explanation of what's going on behind the scenes! +1 [Here's the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/string.py#L48) if anybody's interested. One thing that I think should be made more explicit though is that doing something like `"Men's L/s button-up".split(" \-")` won't work, because as you stated, `str.split` considers its argument to be a single pattern, not individual characters.

Comment: I think I like your answer better though. It makes more sense to me to explicitly define the rules for what's a token and what's not, rather than trying to deal with various separators. Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

The way I would approach this is by splitting up each word you want to capitalize (using `re.split`), capitalize said word (using `str.capitalize`), and then recombine the words to get a single string (using `str.join`):

```
>>> from re import split
>>> 
>>> string = "Men's L/s button-up"
>>> ''.join([word.capitalize() for word in split("([ /-])", string)])
"Men's L/S Button-Up"
>>
```

If you need to split on more punctuation characters, simply add them to the regular expression. For example, if you do decide you need to capitalize words/characters after apostrophes, adding:

```
"([ '/-])"
```

to the regular expression would work:

```
>>> ''.join([word.capitalize() for word in split("([ '/-])", string)])
"Men'S L/S Button-Up"
>>>
```

Comment: I really like how our answers complement each other, mine allows to define what a token is, and yours allows to define what space and punctuation are!

Comment: Lol, yeah, I didn't notice that @araraonline As the old adage goes, great minds think alike :-)